# How to filter particular column in datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I Have to filter a particular column in my data table.

here is my code

```
 string Groupname = txtGroup.Text;
 DataTable dt1 = _objGetDataProcess.Getgroupname(Groupname);
```

In dt1 i am getting table like this
[image]

here i have to filter Item column alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var filteredRows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Item") == itemTextToFilter);
```

... case-insensitive:

```
var filteredRows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => string.Equals(row.Field<string>("Item"), itemTextToFilter,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

If you need a new `DataTable` use `filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()`.

If you want to find also sub-strings:

```
var filteredRows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Item").Contains(itemTextToFilter));
```

... case-insensitive:

```
var filteredRows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Item").IndexOf(itemTextToFilter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: could u tell me what is 'itemTextToFilter'

Comment: @user3494471: the part that i was missing, the string you want to filter by.